# compute the network proprieties: such as degree distribution, density, diameter with python

Tags: networkx

I have a dataset csv with 2 column user_a and user_b (Total 1900655 rows), Each rows are friendship connection.

Per each couple of users which are direct friends, the connection edge is undirected

Column user_a contains the user's id. Column user_b contains the id of a friend of user_a.

```
user_a,user_b
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
0,5
0,6
0,7
0,8
0,9
0,10
0,11
0,12
0,13
....
196584,196537
196585,196539
196586,196539
196587,196540
196588,196540
196589,196547
196590,196561
```

in order to find network proprieties: such as degree distribution, density, diameter i used networkx when i run the the following code i only have to use python.

```
import inline
import matplotlib
import networkx as nx
import community
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#%matplotlib.inline


with open("user_social.csv","r") as inf:
    next(inf, '')   # skip a line
    G = nx.read_edgelist(inf, delimiter=',', nodetype=int, encoding="utf-8")


#print nx.info(G)
print("Number of nodes in the graph")
print(len(G.nodes()))
print("Number of edges in the graph")
print(len(G.edges()))
print nx.diameter(G)

spring_pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

#plt.axis("off")
#nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = spring_pos, with_labels = False, node_size = 35)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.axis('off')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=600,node_color="blue",alpha=0.3)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.3)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
plt.show(G)
```

its only show the following result

```
Number of nodes in the graph
196591
Number of edges in the graph
950327
```

and its keep runs many hours with out any other graph or result or any error. I am very new to python and maybe i missed something on my code, so how can change my code to compute the degree distribution, density, diameter with python?

Comment: Finding the diameter of a graph is computationally pretty expensive. You need to compute the shortest path for all pairs of nodes. The time complexity is at least `O(|V|^2*log(|V|) + |V|*|E|)`, where `|V|` is the number of nodes and `|E|` is the number of edges. Also, when plotting a graph of this size, you will probably run out of working memory (it will probably just be a big hairball anyway, so I would not bother plotting the whole thing).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use tools like Gephi https://gephi.org/ to acquire network statistics. Alternatively you can use a network database system like NEO4J https://neo4j.com and then run queries to know about your data. The advantage of using db systems like NEO4J is that you can save and manage all your information at one place.